# Extracting lists from pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to extract all cases where digits appear in a list in my a column in my dataframe

Using this as a sample:

```
':[{"id":836890 name:"Rob Rubnitz" scorecard:[40 35]} {"id":401538 name:"Steve Weisfeld" scorecard:[40 35]} {"id":799385 name:"Marc Werlinsky" scorecard:[40 35]}] '
```

I would like to extract [40 35] [40 35] [40 35] and have these as the numbers appearing in the updated column.

This is what I tried:

```
data['col'].str.extract('scorecard:(?P<scorecards>.*?)}')
```

The problem is that this only extracts the first scorecard from my column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `extractall`

```
data['col'].str.extractall('scorecard:(?P<scorecards>.*?)}')

        scorecards
  match           
0 0        [40 35]
  1        [40 35]
  2        [40 35]
```

---

#### `findall`

```
data['col'].str.findall('scorecard:(.*?)}')

0    [[40 35], [40 35], [40 35]]
Name: col, dtype: object
```